# Decimal.Parse/Double.Parse Returns a Value without the Decimal Point

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am working with workflows in Sharepoint 2007. In the Workflow I am accessing a Inforpath form the Code Behind and add some Recurring values to a Sharepoint List.

```
string strProfitMargin = ProfitMargin;

decimal margin1 = decimal.Parse(strProfitMargin);

listItem["Test9"] = Math.Round(margin1, 2).ToString();
```

Suppose for the ProfitMargin I get a value `"0.4230769230769231"`.

`Decimal.Parse` Method Returns `4230769230769231` without the Decimal point. Ultimately Math.Round also not working. This works perfectly in my machine. But in QA servers Its not Working. Please Help me and Explain why the decimal.Parse method not Working? Same Way for double.Parse() is returning a value without a decimal.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `decimal.Parse("0.4230769230769231")` returns `0.4230769230769231` for me. What culture is this running under?

Comment: Our Servers are in Germany. I think it should be "de-DE". Is that the reason.Thanx.

Comment: Yes, most likely. That culture uses `,` for a decimal separator. Parse using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or use a decimal literal that uses `,` instead of a `,`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My strong suspicion is that you're running on a machine with a culture which doesn't use `.` as a decimal point.

Specify the culture explicitly, e.g. to the invariant culture

```
decimal margin1 = decimal.Parse(strProfitMargin, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this method. Our Servers are in Germany. But already there are Double.Parse() methods in Web parts which works fine. Thank your for your answer.